# Is Poll call during kafka rebalancing a busy wait?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using manual kafka commit by setting property `enable.auto.commit` as `false` while initialising the Kafka consumer and calling kafka commit manually after receiving and processing the message.

However since the processing of message in my consumer is time taking, I am getting `Exception with message "error": "Broker: Group rebalance in progress"`

The reason being that commit after rebalance timeout is rejected with this error. Now the recovery action for this is either I exit and re-instantiate the process which will trigger rebalancing and partition assignment again. Another way is to catch this exception and then continue as usual which will work correctly only if the `poll()` call is blocked till the rebalancing is complete, otherwise it will fetch the next packet from the batch and might process and commit it successfully leading to loss of the message whose commit got failed while rebalancing.

So, Need to know what is the correct way to handle this case, should I re-instantiate the process or should I catch and ignore the exception?

Comment: Take a look at this : https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync-java.time.Duration-

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to ignore if it happens occasionally, and if it happens frequently then reduce the `max.poll.records` or increase the `max.poll.interval.ms` to ensure it does only happen occasionally. Also, ensure that your code can handle duplicate records (if you can't do that then there is a different answer).

The error you see is, as you probably realise, just because by the time the consumer committed, the group had decided that it had probably gone and so it's partitions were picked up by a different consumer as part of a rebalance - the new consumer would have started from the last committed offset, hence duplicates.

Given that the original consumer is alive and well it will no doubt poll again and so trigger another rebalance. This poll won't block waiting for rebalance to occur - each poll allows for some communication about the current state of the group (within the polling thread)  and after a number of polls the new allocation of partitions will be agreed and accepted after which the rebalance is considered compete and that poll will tell the consumer it's partition allocation and return a set of records.